# jquery menu issue on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a menu in my website, this menu have 4 submenu.

But there is a problem on page reload / page load.

This is my page: http://www.substellar.it/nepsrl/

if you try to refresh the page, you'll notice that the 4 sub menus for one second are still visible.

Why?

This is the script that manages the submen:

http://www.substellar.it/nepsrl/js/menu.js

I can not solve this annoying problem graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you hide your menu after page is loaded. Instead of use `$( ".nep-submenu1" ).hide();`, you should hidde your menu on your html or css like this:

html:

`<div class="nep-submenu1" style="display: none;">`

css:

```
.nep-submenu1{
   display:none;
 }
```